How to capitalize a string that is part of a class in python?
I am working through an exercise in python, telling me to make a class called restaurant along with attributes that are  - name and cuisine types. I managed to complete the exercise just fine, but i wondered what i can do to make the first letter in the names of the restaurant in the output capitalized
(i.e macdonalds -> Macdonalds ; pho hung -> Pho Hung)
My answer:
class Restaurant:
    def __init__ (self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.type = cuisine_type
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"This restaurants name is: '{self.name}' and serves {self.type}")
    def restaurant_open(self):
        print(f"'{self.name}' is currently open")

res1 = Restaurant('pho hung','vietnamese pho')
res1.describe_restaurant()

res2 = Restaurant('macdonalds','american fast')
res2.describe_restaurant()
res2.restaurant_open()

exercise description
TLDR: how to make a class method print a capitalize string as output

This question is similar to: How can I capitalize the first letter of each word in a string?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using a site search. Note there are also many other duplicates, and near duplicates, in the search results list.

The answer to this very straightforward.
class Restaurant:
    def __init__ (self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.type = cuisine_type
        
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"This restaurant's name is: '{self.name.title()}' and serves {self.type}")
        
    def restaurant_open(self):
        print(f"'{self.name.title()}' is currently open")

res1 = Restaurant('pho hung', 'vietnamese pho')
res1.describe_restaurant()

res2 = Restaurant('macdonalds', 'american fast')
res2.describe_restaurant()
res2.restaurant_open()

Output would be:
This restaurant's name is: 'Pho Hung' and serves vietnamese pho
This restaurant's name is: 'Macdonalds' and serves american fast
'Macdonalds' is currently open

Reference:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title

